# Need I add `__all__` list infront of the python model?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some util modules in Python3.10 and want that all function or class defined in
leaf node `.py` files can be import easily. Consider the following file sturctures:

```bash
A0
├─ B0
│    ├─ __init__.py
│    └─ b0.py
├─ B1
│    ├─ __init__.py
│    └─ b1.py
└─ __init__.py
```

Where b0.py is difined as:

```py
# __all__ = ['func_b0']
def func_b0():...
def _func_b0():...
def __func_b0():...
```

If I write `from .b0 import *` into `A0/B0/__init__.py`, then I can use `from A0.B0 import func_b0` in external file to use my custom function `func_b0` easily, instead of use `from A0.B0.b0 import func_b0`.

My question is, need I add such as `__all__ = ['func_b0']` into `A0/B0/b0.py` to control
`A0/B0/__init__.py`'s `import *` behavior? If I use private methods, i.e., `underline` or `double underline`, I can also control the `import *` behavior.

In my opinion, using private methods is a better way to control
`import *` behavior, since only one change is required during maintenance. However, the former `__all__=[...]` method needs to maintain an additional list.

So, is `__all__` not designed to be used here? Is there any `PEP` to discuss this problem (i.e., maybe import alias)?

Comment: you dont need to use `__all__` in `b0.py` file, just use it in `__init__.py` file and define wh ich method you want let the user access through `from A0.B0 import <*/some methods>` method . if user import without this  from .py file directly like `from A0.BO.b0 import *` and you dont want to expose the private methods in  this manner then you need to use `__all__` in the `.py` file

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#global-variable-names suggests a semantic distinction between `__all__` as meaning _"make these vars available via `import *`"_ and underscore-prefix meaning _"private var - avoid using as a 3rd party"_. In practice they probably usually coincide completely though. See comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python